# Forwarding a port in docker-compose without having to open an SSH connection with the -L option specified

Tags: ssh, docker, kubernetes

I've been following [this](https://www.cloudgear.net/blog/2015/5-minutes-kubernetes-setup/) tutorial on getting started with Kubernetes using Docker containers, which is a variation of [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md) official tutorial modified to use `docker-compose`.

I've managed to get as far as listing the nodes using

```
kubectl get nodes
```

but I can only do that if I have an SSH connection open to the container in another window, opened using

```
docker-machine ssh docker-vm -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

**This is quite messy and I'd like to be able to handle this in the `docker-compose.yml`, but I don't know how**

I've tried using the `ports` and `expose` options in the iml file, but they do not work. When I try to forward/expose port 8080 and get the nodes using the above `kubectl` command, I get the following error:

```
error: couldn't read version from server: Get http://localhost:8080/api: EOF
```

I've used the `docker-compose.yml` from the first link at the top, and made the following modifications:

```
aipserver:
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
expose:
  - "8080"
```

I've tried this on all of the containers specified in the `docker-compose.yml`, but the problem persists.

How can I use the `docker-compose.yml` to forward/expose ports on my containers without having to open an SSH connection with the `-L` option specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API server is exposed on the host network on 127.0.0.1:8080

If you want to expose it on the docker-machine vm you need to change the --address flag to be --address=0.0.0.0:8080 instead of --address=127.0.0.1:8080

That will expose it on the VM's address on your machine (e.g. 1.2.3.4)

If you have virtual box port-forwarding set up correctly, this will also make it available at localhost:8080 on your machine.